# Как правильно написать "3-4-классниками"?

Tags: орфография, числительные, сложные-прилагательные

Как правильно написать "3-4-классниками"? И обоснуйте,пожалуйста

Comment: А как будете произносить-выговаривать это "3-4-классниками", если тройка — третьеклассники, а четвёрка — четырёхклассники?

Comment: Произносить надо правильно: третье- и четвероклассники (третьеклассники, четвероклассники). Отсутствие единообразия в произношении – не помеха. Так у Мильчина: 1-, 2- и 3-секционные шкафы.

Comment: Пусть так, хотя у НТ-СС Ефремовой: четырёхклассник м. — ученик четвертого класса. «Третье- и четвероклассники»? Откуда же И взялось? Там тире стоит.

Comment: @shampar Вы правы, в этом случае И не произносится. Произнести такое нелегко. Но не все, что написано, легко произнести (формулы, например). Мильчин рекомендует такие формы для  изданий деловой и научной литератур.

Comment: Интересно, как бы произнесли «3—5-классники» те самые, которые «матерились хуже сантехника». Словами интервал-то вообще не передать. Разве только трёхэтажным.

Answer (score 1):

Могу сослаться на пример из Нацкорпуса:

*[Dar0, муж] У выхода на парковку стояли, курили какие-то девочки, буквально 3—5-классники, а то и еще младше — матерились хуже сантехника. [коллективный. Форум: «Школа» Гай Германики (2010-2011)]*

Обратите внимание на разницу между тире и дефисом.
Тире используется: для  обозначения интервалов (3—4); в случае «то ли то, то ли другое число», но только при цифровой форме. Дефис присоединяет цифру к существительному или прилагательному (4-классники).

Еще вариант:

**3-, 4- и 5-классники**; **3- и 4-классники**

Пример : 1-, 2- и 3-секционные шкафы; 3- и 4-красочные машины (6.3.3 в "[Справочнике издателя](https://img.artlebedev.ru/izdal/spravochnik-izdatelya-i-avtora/Milchin-Numbers.pdf)" Мильчина)

Comment: Я вам плюсанул, но есть большое сомнение, что ***номер*** класса подчиняется тем же  правилам, что и ***количество*** секций. В примерах-то речь идет об образованиях от количественных числительных, а у классов вернее всего - порядковые.

Answer (score 0):

Все плохо. Только **третье- и четвероклассники**, но так не говорят, языку тяжело. Разумеется, если речь идет об учащихся третьих и четвертых классов, а не о чем-то более хитром. Так лучше всего и переделать. ***"Учащиеся 3,4-х классов"***. Тут есть варианты в зависимости от числа этих третьих и четвертых (*"Учащиеся 3,4-го классов"*, *"Учащиеся 3,4-го класса", *"Учащиеся 3-го, 4-х классов"*)  Правда и здесь можно придраться, ибо числительные до десяти вне технического текста пишутся словами.

Вот достаточное осмысленное, хотя и совершенно не авторитетное [пояснение](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BA_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC_%D0%B2_%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B5_%D0%B2_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B5).

Вариант с "И" (см. М_Г и Мильчина) - это было бы идеально, но там примеры на другую ситуацию, объекты имеют три элемента чего-то, а не находятся в третьем классе. 3- и 4-класники - это (в лучшем случае) лица, имеющие подобный образовательный уровень или, например, уровень классности, зашиты, допуска к чему-то. Не думаю, что подобные профжаргонизмы актуальны в обычном тексте.

Comment: "ну думаю"?! Описка? Похоже, имелось в виду "не думаю".

Comment: @М_Г да. исправил.